# I do not get any ether when mining

Tags: mining, ether, mining-pools

I'm mining on nanopool with Claymore's miner.
This is the batch file:

```
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
```

> EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999 -ewal      0x2Da97a1Ad55e270Ae53441fF4f70b501F58b8cbe/rx470/xxx@yyy.de

I don't need geth since I'm mining on a pool right? When I check MyEtherWallet it still prints 0 after 9h of mining with 25 MH/s. Nanopool pays out 4 times a day minimum 0.1 ETH. I already had this problem with ethpool after mining a whole evening and night.

Edit:
I created an account at MyEtherWallet and check my balance by private key. The address in the script matches my wallet - double checked.

Comment: But it shows 0.000 not even something like 0.05. It's a pure zero, am I doing anything wrong? Edit: Ok, thanks for the info. I didn't know I could also view my balance at the pools website. Nanopool's site shows I have a current balance of 0.05573789 ETH.
Thanks. This problem is therefore solved.

Comment: Did you get your ETH?

Answer (score 4):

From [Ethereum Mining Calculator](https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator), your 25 MH/s will earn you 0.14934 ETH per day:

[image]

It will therefore take 0.1 / 0.14934 x 24 = 16.07 hours to earn 0.1 ETH. On your mining pool website, you generally are able to enter your address and get the statistics on your miner.